# `%_` and detecting unwanted named arguments to a method

Tags: raku

As I understand, a named argument to a method goes to `%_` if not found in the signature (not sure why!). To detect this, I do

```
die "Extra args passed" if %_;
```

for the methods I remember to do and that are worth doing. Is there a way to automate this for example with some decorator kind of thing? Or I miss and `%_` is actually a very useful thing in object oriented Raku programming?

Comment: Rationale is **Interface Consistency**: [Apocalypse #12](https://raku.org/archive/doc/design/apo/A12.html#Interface%20Consistency), [Synopsis #12](https://design.raku.org/S12.html#Interface_Consistency).

Comment: I can’t answer your actual question. But I can offer that `%_` is probably spelled like that to rhyme with Perl’s default argument, `$_` (aka the *topic*). The `%` part is simply because it’s a hash (and must be - for possible extra names arguments).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to automate this for example with some decorator kind of thing?

Because this is Raku where there's always More Than One Way To Do It, there are in fact *multiple* ways to fairly easily prevent the automatic `*%_` method parameter.  I'll show you two (and explain how they work) and then try to convince you that, in fact "`%_` is actually a very useful thing in object oriented Raku programming".

### The answer: rejecting unexpected named parameters (the `*%_`)

Consider this code:

```raku
class C0           { method m        { say 'm called' } }
class C1           { method m(*% ()) { say 'm called' } }
class C2 is hidden { method m        { say 'm called' } }

my $c = C0.new;
$c.m(:unexpected); # OUTPUT: «m called»
```

`C0` is a standard class and, as you've already noted, it happily accepts unexpected named arguments.  But if we try the same thing with `C1`, we'd get this error:

```
Unexpected named argument 'unexpected' passed in sub-signature
```

And, if we tried it with `C2`, we'd get this very similar one:

```
Unexpected named argument 'unexpected' passed
```

The biggest difference for our current purposes is that `C1` just disallowed unexpected named arguments for `m` – we could create other `C1` methods that *do* accept unexpected named arguments.  Conversely, with `C2`, we prevent *any* of the classes methods from accepting unexpected named arguments (and do a bit more, but more on that soon).

#### How do these each work?

##### C1

`C1` prevents `m` from accepting any unexpected arguments by using [named slurpy parameter](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Positional_vs._named_arguments) and then [destructuring](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Destructuring_arguments) that parameter into a [sub-signature](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Sub-signatures) – in this case, a sub-signature that happens to consist of an empty list.

Breaking that down a bit, consider this code:

```raku
sub f(:$group-name!, *@ids (Int, Int?, Int?, Int?) {}
```

That signature is saying "I have to have a :group-name parameter and some number of @ids.  And those @ids must have at least one Int, and could have up to four Ints – but no more than four, and no non-Ints)".  So we can call `f` with `:group-name<foo>, 1`.  Or with `:group-name<foo>, 1, 42, 55`.  But if we tried to call it with `:group-name<foo>, 1, 42, 55, 9, 9, 9`, we'd get the error: `Too many positionals passed to 'f'; expected 1 to 4 arguments but got 6 in sub-signature of parameter @ids`.

So what's the signature in `C1`'s `m` method saying.  Well, the `*%` part says "I'll take a list of absolutely any named argument at all" and then the  `()` part adds "so long as that list doesn't have anything in it!".

And that gets us exactly what you were looking for: a method that rejects unexpected named arguments (and *expected* named arguments don't pose any problem at all – you'd declare those before the `*%`, and they'd be handled before ever reaching the sub-signature.

##### C2

`C2` is both simpler and, at the same time, a bit more overkill.  `C2` uses the [`hidden` trait](https://docs.raku.org/routine/hides) which stops `C2` from participating in the [redistpatch](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Re-dispatching) process – and, as a side effect, prevents `C2`'s methods from being given an automatic `*%_` parameter.

Explaining the full scope of Raku's (re) dispatch process is beyond the scope of this answer but I'll just say that, depending on what you want, that may be exactly what you're looking for or it may be an unwanted consequence.

### But you should (maybe) ignore those answers

Let's go back to how you ended your ques ion.  You asked whether you missed something that makes `*%_` "actually a very useful thing in object oriented Raku programming".  I'd argue that, yes, the automatic addition of `*%_` is in fact very helpful.

There are a bunch of different ways to come at why that's the case but, since you mentioned object-oriented Raku, I'll come at it from that angle (I personally write more functional-programming Raku, but the both have there place).

So from an OOP perspective, the addition of `*%_` makes it **much** easier to write Raku methods that follow the [Liskov_substitution_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (aka, the `L` in [SOLID OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).

I'm not sure how familiar you are with that principle, so I'll say just a few words about it (apologizes if I'm belaboring the obvious).  The LSP says that "Objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program".

That can be a bit abstract, so here's a Raku example that's … ok, still kind of abstract, but bear with me.

So, consider the Raku `Stash` class.  It doesn't matter what it does right now; I'm bringing it up because of its type graph:

[image: Type graph for Stash]

So a `Stash isa Hash` and a `Hash isa Map` and a `Map isa Cool` and a `Cool isa Mu`.  So that means that any function that's type-constrained with *any* of `Stash`, `Hash`, `Map`, `Cool`, or `Mu` will accept a `Stash` – and it's up to `Stash` to make sure that it *can* be validly passed to any such function without breaking anything.  Of course, for the most part a `Stash` handles this through inheritance: most of the methods that you can call on a `Stash` aren't actually defined *on* the `Stash` – they're inherited and thus are automatically compatible with the superclass method (because they **are** the superclass method).

But, for methods that `Stash` chooses to overwrite, it's part of `Stash`'s job to make sure that it doesn't break any superclasses expected behavior.  And the same goes for, say, `Map` – but even more so.  If there's a method on `Cool` that `Map` overrides, `Map` needs to think not only about `Map`'s callers but also about `Stash`'s callers: after all, `Stash` might *not* override that method.   So `Map` needs to make sure that it can handle anything `Cool` wants/needs to handle – and that's something that, in theory, could happen at any time.  <sub>(In practice, of course, `Cool` is pretty stable and both it and `Map` are part of Rakudo.  But the same thing would apply for 3rd-party classes, where APIs change more rapidly and you may not have the ability to coordinate changes.)</sub>

In particular, "handling anything `Cool` can handle" means being able to be called with the arguments callers of `Cool` passed *without* throwing type errors – even when those arguments might change.

And that's where `*%_` comes in.  Unless one of them opts out, every member of the [method chain](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#index-entry-MRO) accepts any named parameter.  As a result, `Cool` can freely add new named parameters, and `Map`/`Stash`'s callers (who, after all, aren't supposed to care or *need to care* whether which object they're calling) can pass in the corresponding named arguments. And, even if those method calls get resolved by a method that's never heard of the new argument, absolutely nothing will break.

<sub>Of course, if it just gets eaten by `*%_`, the new argument won't actually *do* anything, which (depending on the class/method) might not be ideal.  But that's where [re-dispatching](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Re-dispatching) comes back in and lets the intervening class act on the method *and* still pass it on to a superclass.  But, again, that's getting out of scope.</sub>

---

So, after a long answer to a short question, the bottom line is that you *can* prevent a method from accepting unexpected named arguments.  But, depending on your approach to programming/Raku, there are some very good reasons to consider not doing so.

Comment: (oh, and all of the above was basically just an elaboration of the two links @raiph posted in the comments to the question.  So check those out if you want more more info.)

Comment: thanks do you know why a method like `CALL-ME` won't issue "Unexpected name argument $extra passed" but fail with "Cannot resolve caller..."? Both `is hidden` and `*% ()` make it fail and that's fine but they fail differently (not from each other but from "Unexpected..." message). [here is a MRE](https://glot.io/snippets/g6za46ytms). Looked at the apocalypse and synopsis links but couldn't find answer. FWIW also confirmed its not due to `multi` because tried with a "normal" multi method and it errs "Unexpected arg...".

Comment: @doesitmatter because it's a multi method.  Without the `multi`, that code produces the error with "Unexpected..."

Comment: oh and here I'm saying "confirmed not due to multi" etc. what do I know sorry for the waste of time there

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to automate this for example with some decorator kind of thing?

I'm not aware of a way of doing that currently.

I once developed a method trait to remove the implicit `*%_` from the signature of a method.  In the hopes I could simplify dispatching on multi methods that take many different (combinations) of named arguments.

It did not end well.  I don't recall exactly why anymore, but I decided to postpone trying to do that until after the RakuAST branch has landed.

Answer (score 5):

> Or I miss and %_ is actually a very useful thing in object oriented
> Raku programming?

I think, it is useful for something like following:

```raku
class F {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;
    multi method w-sum (:$x,:$y) { $x*$!x + $y*$!y };
}

class F3 is F {
        has $.z;
        method w-sum (:$z) { $z*$!z + callsame }
        # vs method w-sum (:$x, :$y, :$z) { $z*$!z + callwith( :$x, :$y ) }
}

my F3 $point3D .= new: :2x, :3y, :4z, ;

$point3D.w-sum: :1x, :2y, :3z, ;
```

## Explanation:

I use `%_` twice:

1. I call method `w-sum` from `F3` with `x y z`, so
   `%_={x => 1, y => 2}`
2. I call method `w-sum` from `F` by `callsame` with `x y z`, so
   `%_={z => 3}`

try *debug version*:

```raku
class F {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;
    multi method w-sum(:$x,:$y) { say 'from F: ', %_; $x*$!x + $y*$!y }
}

class F3 is F {
        has $.z;
        method w-sum (:$z) { say 'from F3: ', %_; $z*$!z + callsame }
        # vs method w-sum (:$x, :$y, :$z) { $z*$!z + callwith( :$x, :$y) }
}

my F3 $point3D .= new: :2x, :3y, :4z, ;

say $point3D.w-sum: :1x, :2y, :3z, ;
```

```
from F3: {x => 1, y => 2}
from F: {z => 3}
20
```

Comment: I added an explanation in the end of my answer.