# Default value in new method causing object construction to work in an unexpected way

Tags: raku

Can someone help me understand the following behavior?

```
class Box {
    has $.data;

    multi method new($d) {
        say  'here';
        self.bless(data => $d);
    }
}

# construct object with the custom new()
my $box = Box.new('hi');
say $box.data;

# construct object using default new()
my $box2 = Box.new(data => 'be');
say $box2.data;
```

This outputs:

```
here
hi
be
```

OK, perfect, exactly what is expected. However, change the code so the new method `$d` has a default value like this:

```
class Box {
    has $.data;

    multi method new($d = '') {   # we give $d a default value now
        say  'here';
        self.bless(data => $d);
    }
}

my $box = Box.new('hi');
say $box.data;

my $box2 = Box.new(data => 'be');
say $box2.data;
```

You now get this output:

```
here
hi
here  # new method is getting called both times and $.data is not set
```

This is not what I expected. I figured I would get the same output as before. Can someone please explain why I don't get he same output?

**UPDATE:** I notice that if I change the new() signature to:

`multi method new($d = '', *%_ ())`

I can get things to work as expected. But I still don't understand exactly why it didn't work without `*%_ ()` in the first place.

Comment: You discovered the `*% ()` trick before I could finish writing my answer. So since you already know the way around it, the tl;dr of why is "methods get `*%` for free, whether you ask for it or not".

Comment: I didn't even know about *%_ until last week when someone told me about it. I've been using Raku for about a year. So many subtleties to this language.

Comment: With all due respect, I thought (compared to Perl5), that in Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) the `bless` keyword had gone the way of the dodo. There's really only two `bless` code examples in the extant docs: Constructors and Static Fields (Singleton example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two overloads of `new` under consideration here are yours and the one defined on [the top-level type `Mu`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/new#(Mu)_method_new). Namely,

```
multi method new($d)
multi method new(*%attrinit)
```

Or, written more explicitly,

```
multi method new(Box: $d?)
multi method new(Mu: *%attrinit)
```

But, we need to be even more explicit. Because, though it looks like only the latter should match `Box.new(data => 'be')`, the two are in fact both valid candidates. That's because, according to the documentation for [`Method`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Method),

> Methods automatically capture extra named arguments into the special variable `%_`, where other types of Routine will throw at runtime. So
>
> ```
> method x() {}
> ```
>
> is actually equivalent to
>
> ```
> method x(*%_) {}
> ```

and that applies to `multi method` as well. The rationale behind this is to allow methods to forward named arguments that they don't understand to their callers.

So, really, our two overloads are

```
multi method new(Box: $d?, *%_)
multi method new(Mu: *%attrinit)
```

So when we write `Box.new(data => 'be')`, we have two candidates which are valid, and the first one has a more specific invocant (`Box` rather than `Mu`), so it gets called.

In the case *without* the default argument, the candidates look like

```
multi method new(Box: $d, *%_)
multi method new(Mu: *%attrinit)
```

so the first `multi` is only a candidate for invocation if there's one positional argument.

We can use the trick from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71088429/2288659) to suppress this behavior.

```
multi method new($d = '', *% ()) {
    say  "here $d";
    self.bless(data => $d);
}
```

The `*% ()` (the space is important here) is actually a rather neat little trick. The linked answer explains it better than I can, but basically the `*%` part says "I accept any named arguments", and then the `()` is a sub-signature to match against, namely the empty signature. You can't stop a method from accepting named arguments, so this more or less reads as "my method accepts any named arguments, as long as the list of named arguments is equal to the empty list".

Comment: OK, thank you. Very clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question and good Answers already.

However, I think that both depend a little too much on obscure aspects of raku, namely 'bless' and '*% ()' - not to say that these tricks don't have a place, but that the common case given (a positional with default) should not need you to reach for the power tools.

Here's my solution:

```
class Box {
    has $.data = '';            # we give data a default value here

    multi method new($data) {   
        samewith(:$data)        # redespatch positional data as named data
    }   
}
```

Comment: That is really good. Assuming the OP really does just want to convert a positional argument to named in `new`, this is a really clean way to do it.

Comment: Yes - I did assume that default tagged onto the attr was acceptable ... otherwise, I would propose TWEAK for adjustments to initial values (that may apply a default to multiple params and then act accordingly) on the almost complete object